# Error al migrar prestashop. Al cargar la url sale http// en vez de http:// No salen los "dos puntos"

Tags: url, prestashop, migration

He tenido que migrar una web de prestashop.
He cambiado tanto de URL como de servidor pero me da fallo al acceder por web al fronted de la web. 
En principio me ha cargado todo bien, puedo acceder al panel de administración en la nueva url teniendo mi sitio alojado en el nuevo servidor. Pero a la hora de acceder via web y poner el dominio este me lo carga con http// en vez de http://

Me estoy volviendo loco y no veo donde está el fallo.

Agradecería si alguien le ha pasado o sabe de donde puede venir el fallo.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Verifica en la Base de datos, en la tabla ps_configuration los valores de las entradas PS_SHOP_DOMAIN y PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL y también verifica que todo este correcto en la tabla ps_shop_url. D
espués de eso entra al apartado seo/url y regenera el htaccess desde el back-end.

Recuerda que en las tablas configuration y shop_url no debe estar ningún http:// y tampoco ningún https:// . **Sólo debe estar el nombre del dominio ya sea www.dominio.com  o dominio.com.**